# Obtain value tag from xml

Tags: php, arrays, xml, string, parsing

How can i get the value of tag first "Code" for example from this XML?

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <soapenv:Header/>
        <soapenv:Body>
                <wsm:CreateCustomer>
                        <wsm:xmlCustomer>
                                <x60:Customer>
                                        <x60:Code></x60:Code>
                                        <x60:Shippment>
                                                <x60:ShipToAddress>
                                                        <x60:Code></x60:Code>
                                                        <x60:ShipISOCountry></x60:ShipISOCountry>
                                                </x60:ShipToAddress>
                                        </x60:Shippment>
                                </x60:Customer>
                        </wsm:xmlCustomer>
                </wsm:CreateCustomer>
        </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I must use the function SimpleXML? Thanks!

Comment: Please show us what you have tried that isn't working correctly.

Comment: Both the wsm and the x60 namespaces aren't declared, so the XML itself isn't valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use xpath to do this.

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($string);
$result = $xml->xpath('//*/x60:Code');

while(list( , $node) = each($result)) {
    echo 'Code = ',$node,"\n";
    break; 
}
```

Comment: Where am I wrong - http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/bf26205b6335610b00849a1315769d5835263d23

Comment: each deprecated

Comment: wsm namespace is not defined. ,

Comment: break the loop after first record.

Answer (score 0):

```
$crawler = new Crawler($xml); // composer require symfony/dom-crawler
$first = $crawler->filter('Customer')->filter('Code')->text();
$second = $crawler->filter('ShipToAddress')->filter('Code')->text();
```